# After button is clicked, can't disabled another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

so I have 2 buttons(Accept, Deny) which both reveal a related div with another button.

When the 3rd button (For Accept) is clicked, I want to disable the 2nd (Deny) after you click on Accept to slideIn the Accept form and then click on the Send Accept button.

- Click on Accept
- Click on Send Accept
- The Box Deny button should not work anymore

[image]

I remove the class `option` that is used on deny after you click Send Accept, but the action still remains and the Deny button will still work :(

**My codepen:
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/hKDIJ**

HTML

```
<div id="accept" class="option btn_accept">
  Accept
</div>

<div id="deny" class="option btn_deny">
  Deny
</div>

<div id="accept_msg">
<form id="accept_form">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="2">ACCEPT! textarea</textarea>
  <button id="send_accept">SEND ACCEPT</button>
</form>
</div>

<div id="deny_msg">
<form id="deny_form">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="2">DENY! textarea</textarea>
  <button id="send_deny">SEND DENY</button>
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.option').unbind('click').bind("click", function() {

  var user_choice = $(this).attr('id');

  // IF ACCEPT
  if (user_choice === 'accept') {
    $('#accept_msg').slideDown('fast', function() {});
    $('#deny_msg').slideUp('fast', function() {});
    $('.btn_accept').css('background', 'orange');
    $('.btn_deny').css('background', '#ccc');
  // IF DENY
  } else if (user_choice === 'deny') {
    $('#accept_msg').slideUp('fast', function() {});
    $('#deny_msg').slideDown('fast', function() {});
    $('.btn_deny').css('background', 'blue');
    $('.btn_accept').css('background', '#ccc');
  }

});

$('#accept_form').unbind('submit').bind("submit", function() {
  var btn_send_accept = $('#send_accept');
  var btn_deny = $('#deny');

  $(btn_send_accept).css('cursor','auto');
  $(btn_send_accept).css('background','#ccc');
  $(btn_send_accept).text('Sending...');
  $(btn_send_accept).attr("disabled", "disabled");

  $(btn_deny).removeClass('option');
  $(btn_deny).removeClass('btn_deny');
  $(btn_deny).addClass('btn-disabled');
});
```

Any thoughts / tips?

Comment: Have you tried to set the "disabled" attribute of the textarea that you want to disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to disable click event handler:

```
$(btn_deny).off("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the `hasClass` jquery method to stop the action from being processed if you have marked the button as disabled. Example:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('btn-disabled')) {
        /* process button click */
    } else {
        /* cancel */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ".unbind" it after user click "#btn_send_accept"

```
$(btn_deny).removeClass('option');
$(btn_deny).removeClass('btn_deny');
$(btn_deny).addClass('btn-disabled');
$(btn_deny).unbind('click');
```